# exec function only running some commands, won't run echo

Tags: c, exec, echo

I'm trying to run command line arguments (specifically echo) through the exec family of functions. I can get the execv function to run if I write my own executable and run it, but if I try to run touch or echo it returns -1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // exec functions
#include <sys/types.h> // pid_t
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define HIGH 1
#define LOW 0

int digitalWrite(int pin, short type) {

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("pid == %i\n", pid);
        if (type == HIGH) {
            char* args[] = {"echo", "1", ">", "/sys/class/gpio/gpio67/value", NULL};
            int val = execv(args[0], args);
            printf("ran function execl, %i\n", val);
        } else {
            printf("Unable to do anything but set pin to HIGH\n");
        }
    } else if (pid < 0) { // pid < 0
        printf("fork failed\n");
    }

    wait(NULL);
}

int main() {

    printf("Starting digitalWrite\n");

    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);

    printf("Completed digitalWrite()\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Just for context here's my build:

```
$ gcc wiringbeagle.c 
$ ./a.out 
Starting digitalWrite
pid == 0
ran function execl, -1
Completed digitalWrite()
Completed digitalWrite()
$ ls
a.out  wiringbeagle.c
```

The command `echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio67/value` runs fine in the terminal on it's own, and if I create a local file (i.e. touch tmpfile.txt) and try to run `echo hi > tmpfile.txt` it runs as expected in my command line but doesn't run in the program.

I must be not understanding something with execv, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're even *using* `exec` to do this for you. C provides file I/O built in to the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `execv` is the file to be executed. Unlike your shell, `execv` does not search through the directories indicated by the `PATH` environment variable, so you need to give it the complete path to the executable. Unless there is an executable file called `echo` in your current working directory, `execv("echo",...)` will fail with a "file not found" error. (Use `perror` to get better error messages).

If you want to search for the executable as the shell does, use `execvp`. But note that your shell probably executes `echo` as a built-in command, so it won't be the same `echo` as your shell uses. In this case, that's fine.

Once you fix that, you will encounter a different problem. Since you are just invoking a command-line utility with arguments, rather than using a shell, the argument `">"` is just an argument. It is the shell which handles redirections (as well as pipes, quoting, and a bunch of other useful stuff). So all you will accomplish is to send the three arguments to stdout.

You could use the `system` function to execute a command using the shell, or you could set up the redirection yourself by `freopen`ing stdout in your child before doing the `execvp`.

You can get quite a lot of information about system interfaces using the `man` command. For example, to learn what `freopen` does, use `man freopen`. You can also read manpages on the internet, eg. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3.html, but the documentation on your own system is right there, and also applies to the actual version of the software installed on your system (assuming you installed the documentation).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely certain why you're even *using* the `exec` family to run external programs in this case. The C standard library provides *perfectly* adequate file I/O stuff.

For example, you can simply `fopen`, `fprintf`, and `fclose` the file *without* ever starting another external process to do that work for you:

```
int bytesWrit = 0;
FILE *gpioHndl = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio67/value");
if (gpioHndl != NULL) {
    bytesWrit = fprintf(gpioHndl, "1\n");
    fclose(gpioHndl);
}
if (bytesWrit != 2) {
    HandleError();
}
```

This is probably the preferred way to do what you want, which is simply writing a fixed value to a file.

---

In terms of why your `execv` call isn't working (though it's totally irrelevant if you take my advice above), there are several things you need to be aware of.

First, while *some* commands are actually files on the disk that you can `exec`, others *may* be internal `bash` commands<sup>(a)</sup>. On my system, for example:

```
pax:~$ type ftp
ftp is /usr/bin/ftp

pax:~$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

One way to solve this is to run the actual `bash` executable (which, being an on-disk command, *can* be done via `exec`), telling it to run its internal `echo` command. From the command line:

```
pax:~$ bash -c 'echo xyzzy'
xyzzy
```

Second, if want to use redirection, this is normally something that's done by the *shell,* not the `exec` calls or individual executables.

Trying to do redirection via the `exec` family will generally only result in the `>somefile` being passed as a *literal* parameter to the executable (in the `argv` array), *not* being used to attach standard output to a file. In other words, it won't work unless the executable specifically handles redirection, which is rare.

So that means you will have to run the shell with redirection and have it run the executable after performing those redirections, even *if* the command is not an internal one.

Thirdly, if you want the path searched for your executable, `execvp` is the call you want, not `execv` (the latter just uses the file you explicitly provide, either relative from the current working directory or an absolute path like `/bin/ls`). So, in your case, you should either:

- use `execvp` to search the path; or
- fully specify the path with `execv`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The `echo` command, while it is `bash`-internal may also be provided as a separate executable (I believe Posix requires this), so this may not be an issue here. It *may* be an issue if you expect them to act exactly the same in terms of more esoteric arguments :-)

Answer (score 1):

`execv()` does not search the `PATH` environment variable in order to find an executable file.  Per [the Linux `execv()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) (bolded text added):

> ...
>
> **Special semantics for `execlp()`, `execvp()`, and `execvpe()`**
>
> The `execlp()`, `execvp()`, and `execvpe()` functions duplicate the actions
>          of the shell in searching for an executable file **if the specified
>          filename does not contain a slash (/) character**. ...
>
> ...

So, those three will search the `PATH` environment variable if the filename passed does not contain a `/` character.

You're using `execv()`, which is not one of those three.  Therefore, `execv()` will **not** search the `PATH` environment variable.

Since your current working directory doesn't contain an executable file called `echo`, `execv()` fails.

You need to use `execvp()` per [the man page.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use absolute path as first parameter in execv
Then, the correct is:

```
char* args[] = {"/bin/echo","echo", "1", ">", "/sys/class/gpio/gpio67/value", NULL};
```

But to run what you want (put value '1' in file '/sys/class/gpio/gpio67/value'), you need to use command sh:

```
char* args[] = {"/bin/sh", "sh","-c", "/bin/echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio67/value", NULL};
```

The parameter to "sh -c" is a string. Then, you need to put all command together as a string